# Unusual behaviour of any.when() in Joi

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

var schema_1 = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer()
}).when(Joi.object({
    'a': Joi.number().valid(5),
    'b': Joi.number().valid(10),
}), {then: Joi.any().forbidden()})

var schema_2 = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer()
}).when(Joi.object({
    'a': Joi.number().valid(5),
}), {then: Joi.any().forbidden()})

var object = {
    a: 5,
    b: 10
}

schema_1.validate(object) // this throws ValidationError
schema_2.validate(object) // this does not throw any error
```

I was expeting error in `schema_2` also
Why `schema_2` is not showing any error?

Comment: I believe joi wont validate any fields that aren't in the schema. So since b isn't checked for it doesn't fail.

Comment: Seems `when()` working fine. Not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: `schema_2` is not showing any error. I want to see error when `a==5` using when.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add `b` as well in the `schema_2`.

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi')

var schema_1 = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer()
}).when(Joi.object({
    'a': Joi.number().valid(5),
    'b': Joi.number().valid(10),
}), {then: Joi.any().forbidden()})

var schema_2 = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer()
}).when(Joi.object({
    'a': Joi.number().valid(5),
    'b': Joi.any(),
}), {then: Joi.any().forbidden()})

var object = {
    a: 5,
    b: 10
}

schema_1.validate(object) // this throws ValidationError
schema_2.validate(object) // this does not throw any error
```

Here is the result.

```js
const x = schema_1.validate(object) // this throws ValidationError
const y = schema_2.validate(object) // this does not throw any error

console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

```
{ value: { a: 5, b: 10 },
  error:
   { ValidationError: "value" is not allowed _original: { a: 5, b: 10 }, details: [ [Object] ] } }
{ value: { a: 5, b: 10 },
  error:
   { ValidationError: "value" is not allowed _original: { a: 5, b: 10 }, details: [ [Object] ] } }
```